# Set Fixed Height for NSSplitView subview

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nssplitview

OK, so here's the deal :

- I'm having a vertical `NSSplitView` (actually using [**DMSplitView**](https://github.com/malcommac/DMSplitView) sublass) with 2 subviews in it
- I want the bottom one to be of fixed height
- `DMSplitView` manages to "fix" its size under certain conditions (e.g. when the window is resized the bottom view stays as is)
- However, if the user tries to drag-resize the view (although both min/max constraints have been set) he's able to, which means that the bottom view is not of fixed height after all.

And this all of my (related) code :

```
[_mainHorizontalSplitView setMinSize:25 ofSubviewAtIndex:1];
[_mainHorizontalSplitView setMaxSize:25 ofSubviewAtIndex:1];
```

So, any ideas of a possible workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found it (actually a modification to `DMSplitView` delegate) :

```
  - (CGFloat)splitView:(NSSplitView *)splitView 
constrainSplitPosition:(CGFloat)proposedPosition 
           ofSubviewAt:(NSInteger)dividerIndex
  {
       return [self positionOfDividerAtIndex:dividerIndex];
  }
```